# fetch single parent id and all child id

Tags: php, mysql

I want fetch user creator id (Ex: parent ID) and all its child id on same level. But there is only fetch upper level and lower level id. My problem seems to be in sql query.

```
<?php  
    include('config.php');
    $user_level_up=$_SESSION["level"];
    $user_level_down=$_SESSION["level"];
    $user_id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $user_level_up+=1;
    $user_level_down-=1;
    $sql = "select * from users where  level = '$user_level_up' OR 
            level='$user_level_down'"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn , "$sql");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 )
    {
    while( $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {  
    // preparing an array

    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo $row["username"]. "
    (".$row["email"].")"."(".$row["id"]. ")" . "(" . $row['level'] . ")" . "(" . 
    $row['create_user_id'] . ")" ; ?></option>
   <?php  }
   } ?>
```

Comment: I want only upper level id who create user and lower level id related to current user...

Comment: check if it helps roytuts.com/infinite-dynamic-multi-level-nested-category-with-php-and-mysql/

Comment: you're question is very unclear at the moment; do you need to go down all the levels or just one? what is your expected output? what are the error messages you get? I suggest you read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question for more clarity.

Comment: i want show all lower level user who created by user and single upper user...

Answer (score 1):

Use your query like this

```
$sql = "select * from users where  level = '".$user_level_up."' OR 
        level='".$user_level_down."'";
```

Comment: I have use  "select * from users where  create_user_id = '$id' OR id = '$create_user_id'";

Comment: no worries bro. if your problem is solved mark as correct.